# Installing ruby 1.8.7 with ruby 1.9.2

Tags: rvm, ruby-1.8

I have ruby 1.9.2 installed on my system (Ubuntu) using rvm, but one application needs rvm 1.8.7, How shall I install ruby 1.8.7 along with ruby 1.9.2 amd run on my system .

Please guide ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of rvm **is** running different versions of ruby on the same system. So just install ruby 1.8.7:

```
rvm install 1.8.7
```

Then you can either set 1.8.7 as the default (`rvm --default use 1.8.7`) or create a `.rmvrc` file in the directory of your application:

```
cat > /replace-with-your-application-directory/.rvmrc << "EOF"
rvm ruby-1.8.7-p352
EOF
```